# How to capture video frames using gstreamer-sharp

Tags: c#, .net, gstreamer

I'm doing some video processing with an already written application.
Actually, it uses DirectShow (DS) to decode the videostream and process it via callback.
The major drawback is, that many common video-formats cannot be decoded using DS because of missing codecs (this affects most interlaced video-formats like .vob - Files = DVD-Format).
Therefore, I'm looking for some decoding alternative to replace the DirectShow code.
Maybe gstreamer with it's [C# bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gstreamer-sharp.html) could be one.
Unfortunately, there's only little example code how to use it, so it's pretty hard to find some good point for starting.

Maybe anybody has a clue how to begin with gstreamer-sharp and videoframe-callbacks for further processing?

Thanksalot in advance!

Comment: Is a commercial component an option ?

Comment: @Yahia Commercial depends on the license and price - basically yes.

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

See these free + commercial libraries:

- http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/post/fflib-net-released.aspx (free)
- http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/ (commercial)
- http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk.html (commercial)
- http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia-suite.htm?linkid=top (commercial)

Comment: AFAIK, ffmpeg can't do video-processing via (blocking) callback. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Sascha I am not 100% sure but IIRC there was some "video hook" in ffmpeg (may depend on the wrapper used)...

Comment: No chance for gstreamer-sharp? Maybe anything around the appsink-class?

Comment: @Sascha I don't have much knowledge/experience with gstreamer-sharp... and in my experience esp. when it comes to supporting different codecs etc. ffmpeg (btw: gstreamer does use this among other things!) is nice and some commercial components too so that's what I recommended...

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg-sharp is dead unfortunately. I'm using [IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) with an in-house interop layer to do decoding with post processing in managed code.  [Streamcoders](http://www.streamcoders.com/) offers something very similar to that which IIRC is a bit more expensive but won't require you implement the interop code.

Comment: How much time / effort / lines of code did you spent for writing your interop layer?